# Is it possible to detect attempt to install APK targeted for wrong platform?

Tags: android, installation

Is there a way to detect if a package I have and I am trying to install is targeted for the wrong platform? For example, I have a package for x86, but my phone is ARM. The package is technically valid, so the returned `PackageInfo` class will not be corrupt. Upon trying to install, it will just fail, so I want to detect that event but I have no ideas how to do it. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your `build.gradle`:

```
abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"]
```

*syntax may vary, depends on gradle plugin you use.*

Comment: The package is not mine and I am looking to detect the event that the package failed to install just because the targeted platform is different

Comment: It won't fail to install. It will fail on startup. *But I'm not 100% sure.*